# Clicking Jump Link / Target on same page goes back to the top

Tags: html, css

I put two jump links in my navigation. Clicking one of those links from another site (like the main page e.g.) jumps perfectly!

But clicking the target on the same site fails everytime. For a moment it jumps to the target but after a second it goes back to the top of the site.

What I've tried:

The page with the target:

```
<div id="example" class="some classes">

...some content

</div>
```

Navigation:

```
<li id="nav-bprocess" class="stop-click">

     <a class="get-underline" href="/the_page.html#example">To the Jump Target</a>

</li>
```

Comment: Try without site name
`<a class="get-underline" href="#example">To the Jump Target</a>`

Comment: @Jon there is no effect...Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have a live example to share? There is probably something else interfering with that.